# Yii2 Redirect to another action with parameter and prettyUrl

Tags: php, yii2

I have this simple action for the creating functionality.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Horse();
    $model->attributes = \Yii::$app->request->post('Horse');

    if ((\Yii::$app->request->post()) && ($model->validate())) {
        $model->save(false);
        $this->redirect(
            [
                'view',
                'id' => $model->id
            ]
        );
    }

    return $this->render(
        'create',
        [
            'model' => $model,
        ]
    );
}
```

Under **common/config/main.php**, I defined:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

But, when the `$this->redirect` is called, it opens the URL without considering the above configuration.
So, this is what I see:

```
http://traditionalbox.back.dev/horse/view?id=11
```

instead of:

```
http://traditionalbox.back.dev/horse/view/11
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the Rules on your url manager.

Something like:

```
'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

As far as I understand, the *prettyUrl* is just about using the *path* format.

Credits shared with *ezekielnoob*.